# When did the Polyjuice Potion wear off?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter book 7, Harry and Hermione had taken Polyjuice Potion before they set off to Godric Hollow, did they transform back into their original selves when they met Bathilda, or did they transform back into their original selves after they followed Bathilda into her house?

Update: I asked this question because I want to know whether the Polyjuice Potion had worn off before they got attacked in Bathilda's house.

Answer (score 10):

When Voldemort arrives at Bathilda's house and Harry sees them escaping through Voldemort's eyes, they are still disguised (e.g. he sees two middle-aged people disapparating, but knows that one of them is Harry).

> And then his scar burst open and he was Voldemort and he was running across the fetid bedroom, his long white hands clutching at the windowsill as **he glimpsed the bald man and the little woman twist and vanish**, and he screamed with rage, [..]

At this point Harry has another vision of the night his parents were murdered, after which he wakes up and Hermione tells him he's been unconscious for hours. Presumably the Polyjuice potion wore off while he was out cold.

Answer (score 1):

It is stated that Polyjuice potion wears off after an hour. This is explained in Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets. So everything that happened in Bathilda Bagshot's house lasted less than an hour